# Why can't I download wine?

Tags: wine, software-center

I wanted to play [Wonderland Online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wonderland%20online&ia=about), but it said I had to download wine. I went through all the steps but when I tried installing it the software center pops up and gives me this message:

> Not found There isn't a software package called "wine1.7" in your
>   current software sources.

So I tried doing it manually and got this result:

```
E: Unable to locate package wine1.7
E: Couldn't find any packages by regex 'wine1.7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the [PPA](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu);

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

and if that still doesn't work try, this

```
sudo apt-cache search wine | grep wine
```

It will search for your sources for a Wine packages, and only the wine packages!

---

#### Try the following one by one in your terminal:

- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get -f install`
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- `sudo apt-get clean`
- `sudo apt-get autoclean`

and last but not least

- `sudo apt-get update`

Due note that there seems to be more broken then beats the eye. Consider possibly upgrading to [Ubuntu 14.04 the Trusty Thar](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/). Advisably by clean install(CD, remove
current Ubuntu 12.04.5 partition and reinstall Ubuntu with the Ubuntu Trusty Thar 14.04.1 CD/USB.)

Comment: after some further searching it might be some dependencies missing. Run the following `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19850/discussion-on-answer-by-blade19899-why-cant-i-download-wine).

Comment: @Mitch thanks! but user has only 1 rep not enough to talk in chat.

Comment: @blade19899 I tried updating Ubuntu and I go this message: 
Running the 'unity' desktop environment is not fully supported by your graphics hardware. You will maybe end up in a very slow environment after the upgrade. Our advice is to keep the LTS version for now. For more information see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D Do you still want to continue with the upgrade?